# NGINX not caching or saving static files

Tags: nginx

I have ubuntu 14 on AWS ngnix is point to a website. I have tried everything but it does not serve up the static images. when I try to cache them. I have tired every combo of this but every time I go there are no files.

```
location ~* \.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|xml)$ {
  access_log off;
  expires 30d;
}
```

When I go to the directory there is no files in the root path.  Any ideas?

Comment: Show complete server block

Comment: upstream project {
        server 172.21.2.230;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://project;
}
        location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 16h;
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official block usage https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/#

```
    server {
  # Replace this port with the right one for your requirements
  listen 80 default_server;  #could also be 1.2.3.4:80

  # Multiple hostnames separated by spaces.  Replace these as well.
  server_name star.yourdomain.com *.yourdomain.com; # Alternately: _

  root /PATH/TO/WEBROOT;

  error_page 404 errors/404.html;
  access_log logs/star.yourdomain.com.access.log;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  # static file 404's aren't logged and expires header is set to maximum age
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:YOURFCGIPORTHERE;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
```